# vertical align text next to responsive image each in .col-md-*

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Tried two approaches to achieve vertical align text next to responsive image each in a separate .col-md-*

on the child element

```
 .vcenter {
  min-height: 400px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
border: 1px solid red;
float: none;
}
```

and a parent child using table-cell method

```
.parent {
  display: table;
}

.child {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

but as image on left is responsive how do I get to work without a fixed height.

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/silko/jr3b8kL5/13/

Answer (score 0):

just add `line-height: 400px;` to your .child class it will make the text vertically centered.

**Note:** you can use calc and vw and vh to make it flexible, e.g. `line-height: calc(30vw + 30vh);`

```css
.vcenter {
  min-height: 400px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: none;
}

.parent {
  display: table;
}

.child {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
p{
  display: table-cell;
  height: 400px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <picture><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" class="ccm-image-block img-responsive bID-214"></picture>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="ccm-custom-style-main49 child">
        <p>vertical center text when more than one lineihfoiwvowiWOiehfiwhfpwHFPwofhpofhpfhpifhhvciuvcivuwcviwucvwicuwvcwiucvcwuicvwicvwicuwvcwicuvwicuvwicvwciuwcviwcuwv</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** if your text contains multiple lines then you should set the text container's `display` property to `table-cell` and then you can set `vertical-align: middle`.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, apologies forgot to say the text is more than one line. I update the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/silko/jr3b8kL5/13/

Comment: @user3108089 I have updated my answer, see it now, to vertically align multi-line text you should use the display table-cell and then set the vertical-align to middle.